How to display DOI and URL in bibliography references of a LaTeX article?
I'm using \documentclass{amsart} and looking for the best method to properly include and display DOIs and URLs in my LaTeX bibliography. What packages or techniques do you recommend for a clean integration that complies with academic standards? Thanks for your advice!
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
...
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{AMS-bibliography}
\end{document}


Do you plan to submit the document to a journal?

No, but I want to use ams style.

In this case, maybe consider switching to biblatex instead of bibtex. Even if you don't find the exact same style, it is usually much easier to customise and works will with doi/urls
